# Can't build Latex in Atom (even though latexmk works)

Tags: latexmk, linux, atom

I'm having an issue using LaTeX in Atom. Whenever I build, I get `Texification failed! Builder executable 'latexmk' not found.`

- I've installed texlive using [tug.org](https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html). I've added the lines

```
export PATH="/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH"
export MANPATH="/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/doc/man:$MANPATH"
export INFOPATH="/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/doc/info:$INFOPATH"
```

into the .profile file. Latexmk works using the command line (e.g. `latexmk -pdf myfile.tex`).

- I'm using the [latex](https://atom.io/packages/latex) package for Atom. I tried setting Tex path in the settings to `Default`, `/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64-linux/`, `/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin` and `/usr/local/texlive/2020`. None worked.
- I'm running Elementary OS on an old iMac.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed TeX using the BasicTeX package and recently ran in to the same problem after downloading and installing BasicTex2022 on top of my existing BasicTex2021 installation. Atom would no longer build and would throw up the same error, despite `which latexmk` confirming an installation to `/Library/TeX/texbin/latexmk`.

The problem seems to be that latexmk was installed in my 2021 package but not my 2022 installation. Running:

```
tlmgr install latexmk
```

solved the problem for me.

Comment: Hey! I honestly don't remember how, or even if, I solved myself (I got another computer since then). But I will accept the answer anyway :). Thanks for the contribution!

Comment: thanks! as usual I got here from searching for the error as I was trying to solve the problem myself. Since there was no solution, I thought I'd post one for anyone else who finds themselves here...